# Change icns in macOS to gray color via bash or other script?

Tags: bash, icon

I want to change icns (Application icons) in macOS applications to gray color. Is there is any script (bash or AppleScript) to do this?

I need a script because applications folder always changing and no way to change everytime icons in this folder.

Comment: Please add an example. At least for me it's unclear if you want to change the color of a folder of an application, the applications' bundle icon colors or the default icon of the docs the application(s) create.

Comment: Rather than close this as broad, I've put a general answer. If you want to ask a specific question about how to change one specific app, we can link that specific case to this general one and you might get an answer on how to do one app.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Each application is sandboxed, code signed and updated by the Mac App Store update process. Some apps are restricted by system integrity protection.

In specific yes, you could disable sip if needed. You could disable gatekeeper and modify the app and re-enable gatekeeper. The engineering work to maintain a general script would be days to get a framework done and then hours to days Pre update.

Comment: yes i have old macbook and sip is disabled, but I have seen somewhere in internet a bash script it changes 10.10 folders color in to folder look like they was in 10.9 MacOS.